# How to have Tampermonkey script run once per page load?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm trying to make a tampermonkey script that will once run once per page load, and will only run again once the page has been refreshed. Here is my script so far:

```
function(){
 dostuff()
setInterval(location.reload.bind(location), 1000*60*60*24);
}
```

The problem is, tampermonkey will continuously run the script, so dostuff() will just keep running over and over again, which I don't want. I've tried solutions such as GM_setValue and  GM_getValue, but the solutions I found will only run once per install, which I don't want.

Here is a more complete sample of my code, which you can put in for https://stackoverflow.com (WARNING: This will crash your browser!):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';
      if (!sessionStorage.getItem("session")) {
          sessionStorage.setItem("session", "storage");
          myFunction();
      }
})();

function myFunction(){
     if (sessionStorage.getItem("session"));
          const galleryList = document.getElementsByClassName('question-hyperlink');
          for(var y=0; y<galleryList.length;y++){
          GM_openInTab(galleryList[y].href);
          console.log(galleryList[y].href);
          }
setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location), 1000*60*60*24);
          };
```

Comment: `setInterval` is useless here, since when the page it reloaded, this interval does not exist anymore. Replace it with `setTimeout`. Maybe you can set a very short-life cookie right before refreshing, and check for the presence of that cookie before starting your `setTimeout`. If I did not understand your goal correctly, could you add details to your question? Like a clear list of operations that take place (e.g. 1. The user opens the page. 2. `doStuff` should be executed 3. After a delay, the age reloads 4. ...)

Comment: oops, I had it on setTimeout, but forgot to update it after playing around with it. I'll try setting a cookie to see if that works out.

Comment: To clarify, my desired goal is 1. enter webpage, 2. scrape desired links off webpage and open in separate tab. 3. stop running until timeout 4. rerun the script when timeout refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
function() {
  //checks if value exists
  if (!sessionStorage.getItem("___thing___")) {

    //if it does not then set it and run the function
    sessionStorage.setItem("___thing___", "");

    yourFunction();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I see the logic behind this solution, but what happens when I implement it is that, when I open a new tab, it runs yourFunction() as expected, but it keeps looping it, despite sessionStorage being true. This may be due to the way tampermonkey works. It will only stop calling yourFunction() only when I refresh the page and tampermonkey realizes that sessionStorage is true.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an absolute idiot. The script was actually running once correctly, but my document.getElementsByClassName was calling recursively every time it opened a new tab. I just had to add an if statement to check for an element exclusively on the page before it opened and the problem was fixed.